# Convert Data From Rows To Column Using Function Or View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-view, sql-function

I need to convert data from rows to columns in View Or Function,I read about
this statement:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by ColumnName, id
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select value, ColumnName
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

but I want it to be in view or function,
 I try to create this in Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_eForm_Control_Instance
(@EFormID INT)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
    DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
                    from vwE_Form_Control_Instance
                    where EFormID = @EFormID
                    group by FieldName, SortID,EFormID
                    order by SortID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT EFormID, EForm_InstanceID
, ' + @cols + '  from 
             (
                select FieldInstance, FieldName, EForm_InstanceID, EFormID
                from vwE_Form_Control_Instance
                where EFormID = @EFormID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(FieldInstance)
                for FieldName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

    RETURN
```

but it gives me error message " Incorrect Syntax near the keyboard 'DECLARE' "

*I'm using sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

Functions with `RETURN TABLE AS ...` can only be created if what follows is a single SQL statement. This is called an Inline Table-Valued Function. Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

If you have a dynamic SQL query like that you will not be able to do that with a Function or a View. Your only option is to use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I can't join Stored Procedure with other table,Can I?

Comment: @Beaudeep Indeed you can not.

Comment: @Beaudeep You could probably do it with OPENROWSET trickery. But it is best to write the whole query as a dynamic query, not just the PIVOT part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the syntax error is that `RETURNS TABLE` must be followed by a table definition:

```
RETURNS TABLE (
Col1 int, 
Col2 varchar(31),
etc...
)

DECLARE ...
```

However, TT's answer also contains valid points.

Comment: He won't be able to do that since his query is dynamic ie number of columns is not defined at the time of creating the function/view.

Comment: Agreed, his function also can't work for the reasons you stated, I just wanted to point out the exact reason for the syntax error.